Real Gaussian beam type conservation
Real Gaussian beams have quality factor $M^2$ that is higher than 1 while a perfect Gaussian beam has $M^2=1$. Additionally, there's multiple types of real Gaussian beams, for example ones where the waist is identical to the $M^2=1$ case, and beams where the divergence is identical to the $M^2=1$ case. What i don't understand is, if I take a real laser beam of one of these types and reshape it by a lens for example, does the "new beam" have the same type?
Here's an article talking about these different beam types:
https://laserbeamsize.readthedocs.io/en/stable/12-M2-Theory.html
